# Interop.Word doesn't work with Arabic text

Tags: c#, unicode, ms-word, interop, arabic

I'm trying to create a word document using C#.net, what I've done is using Interop.Word using this code :

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */ 

//Start Word and create a new document.
Word._Application oWord;
Word._Document oDoc;
oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = true;
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

//Insert a paragraph at the beginning of the document.
Word.Paragraph oPara1;
oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
oPara1.Range.Text = "Heading 1";
oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;    //24 pt spacing after paragraph.
oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

//Insert a paragraph at the end of the document.
Word.Paragraph oPara2;
object oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
oPara2 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
oPara2.Range.Text = "Heading 2";
oPara2.Format.SpaceAfter = 6;
oPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Everything is working fine except that my text is in Arabic and setting oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = 1; is not working also changing the font name

Can you please figure out why am in this trouble and how can I solve it

Comment: You mean it works OK like this but when you replace "Heading 1" with something in Arabic it doesn't work? What error do you get?

Comment: This seems to work OK with English, Arabic or Hebrew on my machine. Perhaps the error is not related with Arabic? Or there's something else?

Comment: Yes exactly, if I replace Heading 1 with something in Arabic the font.bold and font.Name don't work, the underline, the font color work normal!!

Comment: Don't work like do nothing or throw an error?

Comment: it doesn't work means that the text still not bold (even I tried Bold=1 and Bold=-1) and the font didn't change also (I set the font name to Arabic)

Comment: I solve it guys, I have to use the "Bi" sunch as font.BoldBi or font.NameBi

Answer (score 3):

The solution as [nagham_4ng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756486/nagham-4ng) wrote in the comments above was to use the `Font.NameBi` or `Font.BoldBi` property where appropriate instead of `Font.Name` or `Font.Bold`.